# ¿Por qué el estado en react está undefined si en la consola si aparecen los datos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, consola

No logro entender por qué si en el componentDidMount estoy asignando una variable a un valor en el estado, luego cuando quiero acceder a la variable en otra función más adelante, salta que es undefined.

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Este es valor que asigno al estado (un simple email):

```js
async componentDidMount(){
        const session = await Auth.currentSession();
        const userEmail = session.idToken.payload.email;
        
        this.setState({
            authenticatedUser: userEmail
        })
        // devuelve el email por la consola:
        console.log(this.state.authenticatedUser)
 }
```

Luego lo único que quiero hacer es usar ese email para asignarlo a un valor en un objeto que uso para subir unas imagenes a un servidor.

El error salta en `dirName: this.state.authenticatedUser`

```js
uploadPhoto(e){
        // Codigo se rompe porque dirName es undefined (this.state.authenticatedUser es undefined)
        const configUpload = {
            bucketName: 'servicebucketgallery',
            dirName: this.state.authenticatedUser,
            region: 'eu-west-2',
            accessKeyId: 'AKIASBR5P76CO*****',
            secretAccessKey: 'cU108xOa******'
        }
        
        //Subir las fotos:
        for(let i= 0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
            ReactS3.uploadFile(e.target.files[i], configUpload)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {alert(err)})
        }
    }
```

Imagino que es un error simple pero no lo entiendo.

Código completo:

```js
export default class EditGallery extends Component {

    state = {
        authenticatedUser: ""
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const session = await Auth.currentSession();
        const userEmail = session.idToken.payload.email;
        this.setState({
            authenticatedUser: userEmail
        })
       
        console.log(this.state.authenticatedUser)
    }
      uploadPhoto(e){
        
        const configUpload = {
            bucketName: 'service-image-gallery',
            dirName: this.state.authenticatedUser,
            region: 'eu-west-2',
            accessKeyId: 'AKIASBR5P76COPJYL2VW',
            secretAccessKey: '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'
        }
        for(let i= 0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
            ReactS3.uploadFile(e.target.files[i], configUpload)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {alert(err)})
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.uploadPhoto} />
            </div>
          
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: donde llamas la función `uploadPhoto`?

Comment: en el html abajo. Añado codigo

Comment: Lo que te está pasando es que this es undefined. Seguramente necesites hacer un bind

Comment: Oh cierto, acaba de funcionar haciendo eso.

Comment: o puedes usar arrow functions

Comment: este es un problema de context uploadPhoto es ejecutado en el context del input y no en el de clase. Como menciona Javier puedes usar un arrow function para mitigar el problema, o user bind en el constructor de tu clase, y como respuesta final podrías migrar a funcional components y usar Hooks